# Unable to filter object from json array in groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy

In groovy, I have below object. (Type: [Ljava.lang.Object)

```
 test = [  
   {  
      "id":"rod_1565173117796",
      "userName":"rod",
      "displayName":"Rod",
      "date":1565173117796,
      "comment":"ok"
   },
   {  
      "id":"rod_1565173139923",
      "userName":"rod",
      "displayName":"Rod",
      "date":1565173139923,
      "comment":"fine"
   }
]
```

I want to modify / delete this list of JSON array based on id.

I tried below thing filter the required json object from list.

```
parsedJSON = parser.parseText(test);  
parsedJSON.findAll{ it.id == 'rod_1565173139923' });
```

Which is giving me that

> No such property: id for class: java.lang.String

What wrong i am doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just several syntax fixes and your code works:

```
def test = '''[  
   {  
      "id":"rod_1565173117796",
      "userName":"rod",
      "displayName":"Rod",
      "date":1565173117796,
      "comment":"ok"
   },
   {  
      "id":"rod_1565173139923",
      "userName":"rod",
      "displayName":"Rod",
      "date":1565173139923,
      "comment":"fine"
   }
]'''

def parser = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def parsedJSON = parser.parseText(test);  
def filtered = parsedJSON.findAll{ it.id == 'rod_1565173139923' }
```

Comment: Perfect!
I mixed your last 2 lines to **def filtered = parsedJSON.findAll{ parser.parseText(it).id == 'rod_1565173139923' }**